# Application.js not loading in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm struggling to make javascript work in Rails 6.
For some reason, */app/javascript/packs/application.js* file does not seem to load at all. Consequently, none of the javascript stuff works (like bootstrap popovers, tooltips, etc.).
I have setup Rails 6 according to the official docs to the best of my ability. After searching and testing extensively, I have failed to understand why this is happening.
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
})

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Socialite",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem "bootstrap_form", "~> 4.0"
```

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socialite</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class = "container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-brand"><%= link_to 'Socialite', root_path %></span>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Login', '#' %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Register', '#' %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your `views/layout/application.html.erb` file (or whatever layout file you are using)?

Comment: @RockwellRice Sure! I'll edit it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I did figure out what the problem was! It was because of the `import "../stylesheets/application"` line in `application.js`. Removing it did the trick! I found it through trial and error so I don't understand why that was causing a problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to hit the command : bin/webpack-dev-server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What worked for me was running `./bin/webpack-dev-server` in one terminal window and my rails server in another.